# Given an array with numbers from 1 to a.length, how do i find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying the following code but it cant seem to work.
These are my tests:

1. input = `2,1,3,5,3,2`
   expected output = 3;
2. input = `2,4,3,5,1`
   expected output = -1
3. input = `2,4,3,5,1,7`

Here is the code

```
function FirstDuplicate(array) {
    var a = [5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3];
    var firstDuplicate = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var b = i + 1; b < a.length; b++) {
            if (a[i] === a[b])
                firstDuplicate = a.indexOf(a[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return firstDuplicate;
}
```

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And remember to keep the title as a *short* summary of your problem, and have the main problem and question inside the body itself.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it can't seem to work".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a an empty `Set` and keep adding the elements which are already passed to that `Set`. If a number comes which is already in `Set` then `return` it

```js
function FirstDuplicate(array) {
    let passed = new Set();
    for(let x of array){
      if(passed.has(x)) return x;
      passed.add(x);
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(FirstDuplicate([2,1,3,5,3,2]))
console.log(FirstDuplicate([2,4,3,5,1]))
console.log(FirstDuplicate([2,4,3,5,1,7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the value as key and check if the value has been seen before or not.

```js
function getFirstDuplicate(array) {
   var seen = Object.create(null),
       i = 0,
       value;
   
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       value = array[i];
       if (seen[value]) return value;
       seen[value] = true;
   }
   return -1;
}

console.log(getFirstDuplicate([1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 3]));
console.log(getFirstDuplicate([1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

We just push stuff into an object while we iterate over the array. On first occurrence we set it to true, if we find a true we know we found the first duplicate.

```js
function f (arr) {
  let tmp = {};
  return (arr.find(v => (tmp[v] || (tmp[v] = true) && false)) || -1)
}

console.log(f([2,1,3,5,3,2]))
console.log(f([2,4,3,5,1]))
console.log(f([2,4,3,5,1,7]))
```